# IF statements - How to reduce / simplify the amount of source code

Tags: if-statement, optimization, logic, conditional-statements, code-readability

I'm in trouble trying to reduce this section of code of my function:

```
checkData(day, month, year, area)
{
    if(area == "year" && year == this.year)
        return true;

    if(area == "month" && month == this.div && year == this.year)
        return true;

    if(area == "day" && day == this.day && month == this.div && year == this.year)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

How could I simplify/reduce the amount of source code for these IF clauses?

Comment: as all 3 if clauses return true, you could combine them all into one if statement? would that solve your problem?

Comment: Put them in one if-statement with && to continue the comparisons, instead of nesting it with multiple if-statements

Comment: @rayrayray9151 that will be very long row ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if clauses can be rewritten to:

```
checkData(day, month, year, area)
{
    if(year == this.year) {
        if(area == "year") return true;
        if(month == this.div) {
            if(area == "month") return true;
            if(day == this.day) {
                if(area == "day") return true;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then to:

```
checkData(day, month, year, area)
{
    if(year != this.year) return false;
    if(area == "year") return true;
    if(month != this.div) return false;
    if(area == "month") return true;
    if(day != this.day) return false;
    return area == "day";
}
```

Another possible syntax, depending on the programming language (e.g. C++):

```
checkData(day, month, year, area)
{
    return
        year != this.year ? false : 
        area == "year" ? true :
        month != this.div ? false :
        area == "month" ? true :
        day != this.day ? false :
        area == "day";
}
```

Which could then be written into a single line:

```
checkData(day, month, year, area)
{
    return year != this.year ? false : area == "year" ? true : month != this.div ? false : area == "month" ? true : day != this.day ? false : area == "day";
}
```

Some languages support such kind of syntax (e.g. C#):

```
checkData(day, month, year, area) => year != this.year ? false : area == "year" ? true : month != this.div ? false : area == "month" ? true : day != this.day ? false : area == "day";
```

Comment: nice detailed answer showing many options depending on various languages

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 if statements that return the same true value.  You can use the `||` orelse operator with brackets to combine these statements into one line like this

```
checkData(day, month, year, area){
                if ((area == "year" && year == this.year) || (area == "month" && month == this.div && year == this.year)|| (area == "day" && day == this.day && month == this.div && year == this.year))
                    return true;

                return false;
            }
```

hope this helps

*EDIT* - Are the two later if statements nested inside the first one? hard to tell if was just a formatting issue.. if they are nested then you want the `&&` andalso operator to combine the first if statement with each and then orelse to combine the two like this:

```
checkData(day, month, year, area){
                if (area == "year" && year == this.year) && (area == "month" && month == this.div && year == this.year)
                    || (area == "year" && year == this.year) && (area == "day" && day == this.day && month == this.div && year == this.year)
                    return true;

                return false;
            }
```